# Always Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443

Tags: facebook, ssl, sdk

guys, i always got this error when connect the facebook with php sdk.
i have tried to add "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false", but it is still.
but i use the same code on another project on my local server that is working for me.
those are on my local.
thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you trying to connect using SSL instead of TLS

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i found the reason because my internet routing can not connect the facebook.com 443 port. so i always get the error.